# Help required in converting iPhone App to iPad

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am using the latest Xcode and i created a view based universal app and started building focusing on iPhone and now it is mandatory for me to put it in iPad. I didnt use the Interface builder in the development as more dynamic screen changes were expected from the beginning. In the code i have put all the screens with CGRECTMake(0,0,320,480).

Now when i tried to run the app in a iPad simulator, **the app sticks to the top corners of the simulator with width as 320 and height as 480 and the rest of the screen looks white** instead of coming up in the middle of the screen with a border and 2x options.

I have made the **Main nib file base name (iPad)** property in  .plist file to my iPhone XIB name. I know this is one major reason why the app sticks to the top, but how to make this generic and make my app look proper in iPad?

Kindly help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create your views programatically you have to set everything that has a size twice, once for iPhone/iPod and once for iPad. You can do something like:

```
if ([Utils isIPad]) {
  rect = CGRectMake(0,0,640,1024);
}
else {
  rect = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);      
}
```

[Utils isIPad] would be something like:

```
+ (BOOL)isIPad {
#ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM
    return (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
#else
    return NO;
#endif
}
```

Doing this with nibs is easier and faster, though. You just have to use the correct nib in that case. Something like:

```
if ([Utils isIPad]) {
    login = [[LoginController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginController-iPad" bundle:nil];               
}
else {
    login = [[LoginController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginController" bundle:nil];
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. actually implementing this will make me change the positions of the icons, UILabels,UItextviews etc in the code and its dimensions as i dont have the XIB implemented. Everything is dynamic only, kindly help.

Answer (score 2):

In response to dkk's answer, wouldn't it be more convenient to use the application frame of the main screen? This would return the correct frame size depending on the device without manual checks or hardcoded screen sizes.

```
[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]
```

More info: [UIScreen Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html), refer to the applicationFrame property

Comment: Thank you. I would like to add the same comment please help.. actually implementing this will make me change the positions of the icons, UILabels,UItextviews etc in the code and its dimensions as i dont have the XIB implemented. Everything is dynamic only, so i am not just worried about the screen alone but also the elements inside.

Comment: If your using the same view for both iPhone & iPad, you might get away with setting the appropriate autoresizingMask of your labels, textviews.. if not you'll have to write code that repositions everything and a last resort would be to use 2 different views.

Comment: I prefeer to use the isIPad method since you would be tempted to use percentages of the frame to position elements. And that could cause bugs because when using it in landscape mode, the applicationFrame variable will sometimes return the portrait size.

Comment: & @dkk - Thanks a lot guys, you are awesome. I think i will have to fix this by changing the icon spacing too.. but can we not make this app as the usual iphone app looking typically in the iPad with the 2x option enabled? please help me here